# Python: Issue with plotting time series (date and values) - weird looking plots w image for reference

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

im getting this issue with plotting timeseries data where indexing the date produces weird plots. I have also tried `plot(x='Date', y='values')` but produced weird plots.

```
# splitting the column to account for date time.    
new = df["Gmt time"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
df["Date"]= new[0]
df["Time"]= new[1]

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

[head of data values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUGBW.png)

```
df.plot(x='Date', y='Close')
```

[Output of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnDzD.png)

```
df = df.set_index(df['Date'])
```

[Output of code after setting the date as index.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Wat.png)

really appreciate if you could let me know where my code has gone wrong or an issue to fix the following.

Comment: `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` and then plot.

Comment: Tried `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` problem still seems to persist.

Comment: `new` is not a datetime format it would seem. Hard to determine w/o data. Anyway, `df["Gmt time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Gmt time"]`, then `df['Date'] = df["Gmt time"].dt.date` and `df['Time'] = df["Gmt time"].dt.time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding dayfirst=True in read_csv().
Data was taken from dukascopy as a csv file.